# Is there a market for a Text-based empire-building game?

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics, browser-based-games, text-based

I am working on building a text-based in-browser empire building game. The screen will be split into a console and an EXTREMELY rough vector map of your empire (just squares in a bigger square). Commands such as building and expanding would be typed into the console and automatically reflected in the map. Would there be any market for such a game? Would anyone want to play? To clarify, it would be online and everyone's empire would be in the same 'world'.

Comment: I don't think market research is in the scope of this site.

Comment: This is not a valid question on this site so voting to close, however take a look at [Dwarf fortress](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/) same thing as you describe give or take

Comment: to be honest, it sounds a bit dull to me. It's not that hard to create a graphically more interesting game if you ask me. Even if you're not a designer.

Comment: Would you want to play it? If so, there's at least a small market for it.

Comment: Short of real market research it's all just personal opinion and speculation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'Roguelike' market (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roguelike) but they tend to be free games. Even with no graphics, it wont matter if its fun people will play.